# failed to open stream and inclusion

Tags: php, html

I am trying to make a link to registernumbers.php from my index.php, but I get the following error. As I can read on Stackoverflow, I get this error because I am not giving the full path from the root.

As I see it, I am givning the full path? Does anybody know how to solve this. My cache in MAMP is also turned off.

index.html (Here I link to registernumbers.php. When I click this link the error comes)

```
  <li>
      <a href="php/global/registernumbers.php">Register</a>
  </li>
```

registernumbers.php

```
<?php
if( !isset( $_SESSION ) ) session_start();
?>
<?php include 'resources/includes/header.html';?> <!-- Line 4 -->

<h1>Register Numbers</h1>

</body>
</html>

Warning: include(resources/includes/header.html): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/website/php/global/registernumbers.php on line 4

Warning: include(): Failed opening 'resources/includes/header.html' for inclusion (include_path='.:/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.6.2/lib/php') in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/website/php/global/registernumbers.php on line 4
Register Numbers
```

[image: Header Path]
[image: Register numbers Path]

UPDATED Picture

[image: updated picture from comment]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
../../resources/includes/header.html
```

what this does is take you back to the root folder and then goes to the includes folder via the resources folder.

Comment: Thank you a lot for your answer. Some of it actually works now. I am getting my text I have in my header, but it is not taking my css and js. Works fine on other pages. Do you have any idea why this could be?

Comment: it could be that those references are also wrong. it is wise to include your css via your header so the path to this file will always be the same.

Comment: Hello Bomskie. My header is working fine on all other pages, except this one. I have all my css and js as links in my header.

Comment: what you could try is load up your page and check your source code to see if something is out of place. look good at opening/closing tags are they correct? do you call the header on this page the same as other pages? you'll have to ask these questions while debugging.

Comment: Okay, I just tried to delete my header totally and put in a <h1> headline</h1>. This is working totally fine. So it must be some code in my header, there is not properly closed or something like this, right?

Comment: that is what i ask you to check. just load in your page and rightclick and select view source. this is the easiest way i can think of to check your header and see wether your header closes some tags incorrectly.

Comment: Ah yes of course it is.... When I delete the php/global/registernumbers.php, which is laying in my header, all the header is called fine.

Comment: ah hold on try this: include('../../resources/includes/header.html');

Comment: Still the same :-( I am getting my text, but not the css and js links

Comment: maybe to start of comment all of your php and design the html page as the others wich works. then delete slowly 1/2 components at a time. this way you'll notice if you are missing something and because this file isn't that huge you could try to fix it in this way.

Comment: I found where the error is. In my header.html I have the button link to the registernumbers.php. Everything is working fine, if I delete the path in my header: <a href="php/global/registernumbers.php">Register</a>. When I put the link here again, I get the error.

Comment: When I click the button "register" I have the link <a href="php/global/registernumbers.php">Register</a>. in my header. I get to the page(updated my question with a picture)

Comment: again i think this is a path reference problem. try this: ../../global/registernumbers.php

Comment: Thank you for your time and help. I am just gonna leave the question open, and come back to it later today, and see if there is some other suggestions.

Comment: If anyother have a suggestion, I will be very happy to hear it:) I stil didnt solve this problem yet. The page registernumbers work 100% if I add the ../../resources/includes/header.html infront of css and js. But then all my other pages are not working :-/

Answer (score 0):

You can use **dirname(__DIR__)** untill you get the full path.
Also You can use **DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR** php constant to use the correct directory separator.

Youc can use:

```
define('DS', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);
define('ROOT', dirname(dirname(__DIR__)) . DS); // Use it untill you get the root path.
include ROOT.'resources/includes/header.html';
```

Also You can change **header.html** to **header.php** for easy usage.

Comment: Hello Prince. "Use it untill you get the root path". Is it not the correct rootpath now? I would just like to find a permanent solution on it

Comment: I means to say You can use dirname(dirname(__DIR__)) and so on. When you reach the root directory then include the file.